# JavaME game. Overriding Blackberry keys

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Is any possibility to override this two menu keys (marked on the picture) by my own functionallity?
I would like to override this two keys for specified in game functionality.
[image]

Comment: yes it is possible to override both of this keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override `Menu` button you can go with the following code..

```
public void makeContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
    // Write your code here.
}
```

To override `Back` button there are two options to override `close()` method as well as override `keyDown(int keycode, int time)` method

**1. keyDown(int keycode, int time)**

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
    int key = Keypad.key(keycode);
    if (key == Characters.ESCAPE) {
        // do something here
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
}
```

**2. close()**

```
public boolean onClose() {
    if (someCondition) {
        // do something
        return false;
    } else
        return super.onClose();
}
```